# how can i add a password so only the administrator can get in to the reports in java using GUI?

Tags: java, passwords

my question is how can i add a password that only will appear when the administrator button is clicked and will only access the reports if the password is correct. if my question is not clear please say so, so i explain in a better way

the code is the next one:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String Pass = this.jPFPass.getText();
    password(Contra(Pass));// TODO add your handling code here:
        }    
        private void jButtonAdministradorMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                  
            jDReportes.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jDReportes.setModal(true);
            jDReportes.pack();
            jDReportes.setVisible(true);
        }                             
public String Contra(String pass){
        return pass;
    }
    public boolean password(String pass){
        String passver="Admin";
        if (pass == passver){

    }
        return false;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Netbeans? If so you can try a drag and drop technique because NetBeans incorporates a GUI drop for password.

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html

^That's a tutorial on how to access Netbeans GUI.

Comment: yeah using netbeans but with the drag and drop thing i can input a password text field but then to make sure that the password is correct i have to see if its true or false and only if true the user can acces the reports

Comment: So are you trying to hide the password? As in asterisks replacing the letters?

Comment: this is what i did: String Passw = this.jPFPass.getText();
        password(Contra(Passw));
        while (Pass == true) {
            jDReportes.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jDReportes.setModal(true);
            jDReportes.pack();
            jDReportes.setVisible(true);
        }
        jPFPass.setText("");
    }

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did thanks anyways:

```
    private void jBAcePassActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String Passw = this.jPFPass.getText();
        password(Contra(Passw));
        while (Pass == true) {
            jDReportes.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jDReportes.setModal(true);
            jDReportes.pack();
            jDReportes.setVisible(true);
        }
        jPFPass.setText("");
    }
 private void jButtonAdministradorMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                  
        this.jDVerAdmi.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jDVerAdmi.setModal(true);
        jDVerAdmi.pack();
        jDVerAdmi.setVisible(true);
    }
public boolean password(String pass) {
        String passver = "admin";
        if (pass.equals(passver)) {
            Pass = true;
        } else {
            Pass = false;
        }
        return Pass;
    }
```

basically i did a global parameter that will check if password is equal to input password and if its equal it will change it to True but if its false it wont let you get in